# Popular DropDownList com JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdown

-- Controller --

```
 [WebMethod]
 public ActionResult GetSellers()
 {
    List<Seller> sellers = db.Sellers.ToList();

    return Json(sellers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

-- View --

```
@Html.DropDownList("SellerId", null, "-- Select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

-- Javascript --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#DeptId').change(function () { // DeptId is my another DropDownList
        $.getJSON('/SaleRecords/GetSellers'), null, function (result) { // My path
            var ddl = $('#SellerId'); // My seller DDL
            ddl.empty();
            $('Sellers').show(); // My div (it's display: none)
            $(result).each(function () {
                ddl.append(
                $('<option />', {
                    value: this.Id
                }).html(this.Name)
                );
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

Boa tarde,

O problema desse código aí é que quando executado, não vem os vendedores que o JSON retorna, e sim, retorna 3 registros, já debuguei. O que pode ser?

Answer (score 2):

Achei a resposta, para alguém que no futuro possa precisar, aqui está:

Apenas inseri dentro do meu método, no controller:

```
myContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

O método `each` do jquery recebe dois parâmetros: o índice do objeto no array e o objeto da iteração atual:

```
$(result).each(function (índex, value) { 
   ddl.append( $('<option />', 
     { value: value.Id }).html(value.Name) ); 
});
```

Comment: Troquei aqui, porém, continua sem me retornar os registros.